# Failing to use ArcGIS map as basemap in GeoNode

Tags: layers, geoext, geoexplorer, arcgis-online-basemaps, geonode

I'm trying to add the ArcGIS map service to my project in GeoNode but I'm failing to do so. I've read around and I saw information that says I need to make a XYZ tile service (something like this: `http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}`. So, in the geonode (django) settings there is this by default:

```
MAP_BASELAYERS = [{
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_olsource"},
    "type": "OpenLayers.Layer",
    "args": ["No background"],
    "visibility": False,
    "fixed": True,
    "group":"background"
}, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_osmsource"},
    "type": "OpenLayers.Layer.OSM",
    "name": "mapnik",
    "visibility": True,
    "fixed": True,
    "group": "background"
}, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_mapquestsource"},
    "name": "osm",
    "group": "background",
    "visibility": False
}, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_mapquestsource"},
    "name": "naip",
    "group": "background",
    "visibility": False
}, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_bingsource"},
    "name": "AerialWithLabels",
    "fixed": True,
    "visibility": False,
    "group": "background"
}, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_mapboxsource"},
}
```

This piece of code represent each map that I can use as background. And I'm trying to add the ArcGIS like this>

```
, {
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_arcgisworldtopo",
    "name": "ArcGIS.Layer.XYZ",
    "url": "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"},
    "fixed": True,
    "visibility": False,
    "group": "background"
}
```

This fails and shows no error (nothing in console or browser), just doesn't show any of the options at all the map viewer is blank.

**Anybody have any idea how to do this?**

Just for guiding purposes, here is the link to the ArcGIS World Imagery info: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9 and this is the link to the ArGIS REST API: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer

Comment: Have you tried [gxp_arcrestsource](http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/lib/plugins/ArcRestSource.html)??

Answer (score 1):

Melvin should've just replayed to the thread on the mailing list... Looks like you invented a new gxp prototype that doesn't exist in gxp_arc...

The proper syntax to use is;
source: gxp_olsource 
with type: OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ
You can also add the name as an additional variable like this:
"name":"Name",

Heres a full example:

{
    "source": {"ptype": "gxp_olsource"},
    "type":"OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ",
    "args":[
"hot", ["http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"], {"transitionEffect": "resize","attribution": "osm_attribution"}],
    "name":"HOT",
    "visibility": True,
    "fixed": True,
    "group":"background"
  },

Comment: Yea, I read your post again and I figured it out. Sort of. Type is `OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ` and the link is `http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}` (indifferent if no extension file is given or if I write .jpg or .png)
But.. It gives me only the "thumbnail" of the map multiple times, not the interactive map. I was able to connect to that example with no problem. I read ESRI changed some things regarding its REST service, I'm not sure if it helps.

And I wrote here to see if I covered more ground.